# Can't bundle ruby file. getting error message as cannot load such file.

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to install  a jekyll theme, when I run the command bundle in terminal. i get an error stating 
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in`'

Comment: This was an issue with bundle version `1.16.1` . See more details about it [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2055). Have you got it fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall bundler:

```
gem uninstall bundle
gem install bundle
```

use `sudo` if necessary